# How to view Exception Details Visual Studio "Unhanded exception was encountered during a user callback"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

My Visual Studio devenv.exe crashes intermittently, and if I debug it I see the following:

[image]

Is there any way to view the exception that was thrown so I might have a clue what caused the crash?

What exactly does "user callback" mean in this context that makes it different from just a generic "Unhandled exception" dialog that Visual Studio might display like the following:

[image]

Here is the call stack for my crashed devenv.exe process if that helps explain how to view any exception details.

```
>   user32.dll!_NtUserMessageCall@28()  Unknown
    user32.dll!_NtUserMessageCall@28()  Unknown
    user32.dll!_NtUserQueryWindow@8()   Unknown
    uxtheme.dll!_ThemeDefWindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long,int) Unknown
    uxtheme.dll!_ThemeDefWindowProcW@16()   Unknown
    user32.dll!_DefWindowProcW@16() Unknown
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_CallWindowProcAorW@24() Unknown
    user32.dll!_CallWindowProcW@20()    Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!66288900()   Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for WindowsBase.ni.dll]    
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!66288900()   Unknown
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_CallWindowProcAorW@24() Unknown
    user32.dll!_CallWindowProcW@20()    Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!662a385a()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!662a385a()   Unknown
    004ca2da()  Unknown
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_DispatchClientMessage@24()  Unknown
    user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_NtUserMessageCall@28()  Unknown
    user32.dll!_RealDefWindowProcWorker@24()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_RealDefWindowProcW@16() Unknown
    uxtheme.dll!_ThemeDefWindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long,int) Unknown
    uxtheme.dll!_ThemeDefWindowProcW@16()   Unknown
    user32.dll!_DefWindowProcW@16() Unknown
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_CallWindowProcAorW@24() Unknown
    user32.dll!_CallWindowProcW@20()    Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!66288900()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!66288900()   Unknown
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_CallWindowProcAorW@24() Unknown
    user32.dll!_CallWindowProcW@20()    Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!662a385a()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!662a385a()   Unknown
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_SendMessageWorker@24()  Unknown
    user32.dll!_SendMessageW@16()   Unknown
    02bc900a()  Unknown
    02bc8c27()  Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!66288622()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!6628855a()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!6628ac3c()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!6628ab88()   Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!727ada07()  Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!727ad956()  Unknown
    mscorlib.ni.dll!727ad921()  Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!6628aaab()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!6628742b()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!662875ca()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!6628880b()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!6628875b()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!66288622()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!6628855a()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!66286cfe()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.ni.dll!662880e1()   Unknown
    004ca2da()  Unknown
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()    Unknown
    user32.dll!_DispatchMessageWorker@8()   Unknown
    user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()    Unknown
    msenv.dll!MainMessageLoop::ProcessMessage(struct IMsoStdComponentMgr *,struct IVsWindowManager *,struct tagMSG &)   Unknown
    msenv.dll!CMsoCMHandler::EnvironmentMsgLoop(void)   Unknown
    msenv.dll!CMsoCMHandler::FPushMessageLoop(unsigned long)    Unknown
    msenv.dll!SCM::FPushMessageLoop(class SCMI *,unsigned long,void *)  Unknown
    msenv.dll!SCM_MsoCompMgr::FPushMessageLoop(unsigned long,unsigned long,void *)  Unknown
    msenv.dll!CMsoComponent::PushMsgLoop(unsigned long) Unknown
    msenv.dll!VStudioMainLogged(void)   Unknown
    msenv.dll!_VStudioMain()    Unknown
    devenv.exe!util_CallVsMain(struct MAINPARAM *,int *)    Unknown
    devenv.exe!CDevEnvAppId::Run(unsigned short *,int)  Unknown
    devenv.exe!_WinMain@16()    Unknown
    devenv.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Unknown
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

Comment: Set a break point and step into your code. F10 will call a function and run it to its return statement, F11 will take you into the function and run the code line by line. Usually an unhandled exception is when you are trying to reference heap memory that is either not initialized properly, the memory at that address was released before you started to use it, you are trying to access memory that doesn't belong to you, or in cases of using std::containters, you are going out of bounds of that container.

Comment: Click the checkbox. Also did you walk up the callstack to your code?

Comment: @FrancisCugler I can't step into the code because it isn't my code -- this is Visual Studio's devenv that has crashed and there aren't any publicly available symbols for these dlls as far as I can tell so I can't see the source code where the exception was thrown.

Comment: Enable a break when the exception is thrown (can be annoyance if the program is using exceptions for error reporting)

Comment: @JDiMatteo hmm, I have not encountered that kind of problem. As for your other question about user callback, normally a user callback is a function that is written in the current solution / project that when called or invoked is running code that uses any of these libraries where the unhandled exception is being thrown.

Comment: Maybe a bug report to Microsoft is in order.

Comment: @DieterLücking I'll try that next time it crashes, and start devenv.exe again from that Just-In-Time debugging sln and see if that helps, thanks.

Comment: Has anyone actually had Microsoft productively help them with a visual studio crash or other problem?  I would just assume a huge waste of time with no possible benefit.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has suggested disabling any add-ons you might have installed into Visual Studio. maybe the "user callback" in this case is a callback into an add-on?

Comment: Worst case scenario is to save all of your projects to an external storage, keep track of any system environmental variables you may have created, then uninstall and do a clean install of your version of Visual Studio.